# Does "egourge" in Finnegans Wake derive from the Greek "egoourgos" meaning "worker for the self"?

Tags: james-joyce, word-coinage, finnegans-wake

[Finnwake.com](http://www.finwake.com/1024chapter3/1024finn3.htm) claims that "egourge", in the following line from *Finnegans Wake* (p.g. 49-50), derives from "egoourgos (gr) - worker for the self", but Google Translate does not seem to know of any word "egoourgos".

> Now let the centuple celves of my **egourge** as Micholas de Cusack calls
>   them, — of all of whose I in my hereinafter of course by recourse
>   demission me — by the coincidance of their contraries reamalgamerge in
>   that indentity of undiscernibles where the Baxters and the Fleshmans
>   may they cease to bidivil uns and (but at this poingt though the iron
>   thrust of his cockspurt start might have prepared us we are well- nigh
>   stinkpotthered by the mustardpunge in the tailend) this outandin brown
>   candlestock melt Nolan's into peese!

Can anyone justify this derivation, or source a reference in the literature?

---

I have asked  [essentially the same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504755/how-can-james-joyces-word-egourge-be-seen-via-greek-as-worker-for-the-se) on our sister site [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Interesting question! [Anderson's *Joyce's Finnegans Wake: The Curse of Kabbalah*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XVktuDe1aHUC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=finnegan%27s+wake+egourge) says "egourge" is simply a portmanteau of ego + urge, with no Greek source required. I couldn't find any source in the literature for the connection with "egoourgos".

Comment: @Rand al'Thor Thanks for the reference. Which also makes much more sense to my reading.

Comment: But would be interested if "self-employed" is derivable.

Comment: [Dramaturge](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dramaturge) comes from Greek *dramatourgos,* which breaks down into *drama* + *ergos* (worker). Similarly for [*thamaturge*,](https://www.etymonline.com/word/thaumaturge) from Greek *thamatourgos*. So *egourgos*,  which probably isn't a real Greek word, would presumably be *ego* + *ergos*.

Comment: The "word" *egoourgos* has an extra "o", which not only isn't in *Finnegan's Wake*, but probably wouldn't be in any actual Greek word formed from *ego + ergos*.

Comment: @Peter Shor That's it. Thank you.

Comment: I feel reluctant to write an answer based on my comments, because I don't know any Greek. So somebody else who does, feel free to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: I don't know any Greek (ancient or modern), so trust this answer at your own risk.

[*Dramaturge*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dramaturge) comes from Greek *dramatourgos*, which breaks down into *drama* + *ourgós* (worker). Similarly for [*thamaturge*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/thaumaturge), from Greek *thamatourgos*, which breaks down into *thamato* (wonder) + *ourgós*. So *egourgos* (or *egoourgos*), which isn't a real Greek word, would presumably be *ego* + *ourgós*.

Given James Joyce's facility at languages and his proclivity for inventing new words, this seems like a reasonable derivation for *egourge*.